# Auth0 unsupported_challenge_type error during 2-factor auth

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, auth0, multi-factor-authentication

I want to implement 2-factor sign up with auth0 (username / password and SMS code). I'm not using Lock widget, trying to implement sign-up based on auth0 API instead.

So, I have following steps now.

1 Sign up with

`POST https://somedomain.eu.auth0.com/dbconnections/signup`

```
{
    "client_id":"MY_CLIENT_ID",
    "client_secret":"MY_CLIENT_SECRET",
    "connection": "Username-Password-Authentication",
    "email": "sowhat@what.what",
    "username": "sowhat",
    "password": "sowhat@what.what",
    "phone_number": "+38...56"  // I have access to this number
}
```

Response is created user.

2 Attempt to login with username / password

`POST https://somedomain.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token`

```
{
    "client_id":"MY_CLIENT_ID",
    "client_secret":"MY_CLIENT_SECRET",
    "audience":"http://localhost",
    "email": "sowhat@what.what",
    "username": "sowhat",
    "password": "sowhat@what.what",
    "grant_type":"password"
}
```

Response is `mfa_required` and `mfa_token` string.

3 Requesting mfa challenge

`POST https://somedomain.eu.auth0.com/mfa/challenge`

```
{
    "client_id":"MY_CLIENT_ID",
    "client_secret":"MY_CLIENT_SECRET",
    "challenge_type": "oob otp",
    "mfa_token": "MFA_TOKEN_FROM_PREVIOUS_STEP"
}
```

The response is

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_challenge_type",
    "error_description": "User is not enrolled with guardian"
}
```

So I don't really know how can I fix this one. I guess the reason is probably because phone_number is missing in user profile but I don't actually know how can I add it with `Username-Password-Authentication` connection.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to involve users in 'Guardian'.
Firstly you need enable Guardian Factory:
Just call this: 
    `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %your_token%" -X PUT  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"enabled":true}' "https://%your_domain%/api/v2/guardian/factors/sms"`

And now we can involve users in Guardian:

1. Create ticket:
   `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %your_token%" -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user_id":"%user_id%"}' "https://%your_domain%/api/v2/guardian/enrollments/ticket"`
2. Follow ticket_url in response
3. Put phone number into 
   [opened form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHCuZ.png)
4. Waiting for otp on you device
5. Put otp into early opened form.

After those steps user will be involved in Guardian. It should avoid the problem described above.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have guardian SMS factor configured with twilio connected (`GET /api/v2/guardian/factors` returns `[... {name: sms, enabled: true}]`). I don't have issues with sending SMS using Lock widget (basically what `ticket_url` is). Unfortunately, using Lock widget doesn't meet our requirements as we consider only API usage, that's mean I can't use `ticket_url`.